# How to right-align numeric data?

Tags: python, string, text, formatting

I have some data that I am displaying in 3 column format, of the form:

`key: value key: <tab> key: value <tab> key: value`.

Here's an example:

```
p: 1    sl: 10  afy: 4
q: 12   lg: 10  kla: 3
r: 0    kl: 10  klw: 3
s: 67   vw: 9   jes: 3
t: 16   uw: 9   skw: 3
u: 47   ug: 9   mjl: 3
v: 37   mj: 8   lza: 3
w: 119  fv: 8   fxg: 3
x: 16   fl: 8   aew: 3
```

However, I'd like if the numbers were all right aligned, such as:

```
a:   1
b:  12
c: 123
```

How can I do this in Python?

Here is the existing printing code I have:

```
print(str(chr(i+ord('a'))) + ": " + str(singleArray[i]) + "\t" +
    str(doubleArray[i][0]) + ": " + str(doubleArray[i][1]) + "\t" +
    str(tripleArray[i][0]) + ": " + str(tripleArray[i][1]))
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Python 2.5 use rjust (on strings). Also, try to get used to [string formatting](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html) in python instead of just concatenating strings. Simple example for rjust and string formatting below:

```
width = 10
str_number = str(ord('a'))
print 'a%s' % (str_number.rjust(width))
```

Answer (score 79):

In python 2.6+ (and it's the standard method in 3), the "preferred" method for string formatting is to use string.format() (the complete docs for which can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html?highlight=string%20common%20string%20operations#format-string-syntax)).
right justification can be done with

```
"a string {0:>5}".format(foo)
```

this will use 5 places, however

```
"a string {0:>{1}}".format(foo, width)
```

is also valid and will use the value width as passed to .format().

Comment: I don't know why this answer is voted up since it is incorrect - for right-justification/alignment, it is necessary to use `"{:>5}"` where `>` indicates right-align (the default for strings is `<`, or left-aligned). Luckily, the linked-to documentation makes this clear. (EDIT: never mind, I'll just fix the answer and leave this for reference.)

Comment: It's been upvoted because ">" is the default value of the 'align' field for numbers, and the question was about numbers. You're right, though, that making it explicit is better.

Comment: Mea culpa. I found this question because I was trying to right-align strings, and I didn't read the OP question close enough to catch that only numbers were being printed. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 27):

Use python string formatting: `'%widths'` where width is an integer

```
>>> '%10s' % 10
'        10'
>>> '%10s' % 100000
'    100000'
```

Comment: For left align use '%-10s' (just adding this because it's the top Google result for left align)

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3.6 you can use [Literal String
Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), which is less
verbose and probably more intuitive to use:

```
width = 5
number = 123
print (f'{number:>{width}}')
```

Or just:

```
number = 123
print (f'{number:>5}')
```

It reuses much of the `str.format()` syntax.

I guess/hope this will be the prefered way in the future.

Comment: GitHub: [Using f-strings style literal string interpolation without Python 3.6](https://github.com/damnever/fmt)

Answer (score 2):

If you know aa upper bound for your numbers, you can format with `"%<lenght>d" % n`. Given all those calculations are done and in a list of (char, num):

```
mapping = ((chr(i+ord('a')), singleArray[i]), 
           (doubleArray[i][0],doubleArray[i][1]), 
           (tripleArray[i][0],tripleArray[i][1])
           )
for row in mapping:
   print "%s: %3d" % row
```