# right aligning this column

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I right-align my text in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402048/how-do-i-right-align-my-text-in-python)

```
4   8   12   16   
20   24   28   32   
36   40   44   48   
52   56   60   64   
68   72   76   80   
84   88   92   96   
100   104   108   112   
116   120   124   128   
132   136   140   144   
148   152   156   160
```

Right now I have a column that's like this. Can somebody please help me figure out how to right align the columns so that it looks like this:

```
  4     8    12    16   
 20    24    28    32   
 36    40    44    48   
 52    56    60    64   
 68    72    76    80   
 84    88    92    96   
100   104   108   112   
116   120   124   128   
132   136   140   144   
148   152   156   160
```

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=python+align

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> for line in data:
...     print '   '.join('{:>3}'.format(i) for i in line.split())
...
  4     8    12    16
 20    24    28    32
 36    40    44    48
 52    56    60    64
 68    72    76    80
 84    88    92    96
100   104   108   112
116   120   124   128
132   136   140   144
148   152   156   160
```

See the docs on [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

```
cell_width = 6

for row in data:
    #"%-6s"%val will right format 6  spaces
    print ("%-"+cell_width+"s ")*len(row) % row
```

something like that anyway... I should note that % string formatting is considered depreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

As well as string formatting, there's also a built-in function for string `str.rjust` for this:

```
for line in data.splitlines():
    print ' '.join(el.rjust(5) for el in line.split())
```